# How to handle platform thread without plugin in Flutter from native iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-platform-channel

Since Flutter 3.13 you may have noticed new Flutter errors according your platform channel method invocation (iOS) :

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1015)] The 'CameraController' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading for more information.
```

Inside the [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading), the only example to implement a `TaskQueue` to handle the multi-thread is written for a plugin concept :

```
public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
  let taskQueue = registrar.messenger.makeBackgroundTaskQueue()
  let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.foo",
                                     binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger(),
                                     codec: FlutterStandardMethodCodec.sharedInstance,
                                     taskQueue: taskQueue)
  let instance = MyPlugin()
  registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
}
```

However I'm not using plugins for my iOS channels, I have initialized them all inside the `AppDelegate` like this :

```
let flutterController : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController                    
let cameraChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "CameraController", binaryMessenger: flutterController.binaryMessenger)
```

Then I'm calling from my native iOS channel at app start :

```
private func setupCameraConst() {
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
  channel!.invokeMethod("setAspectRatio", arguments: aspectRatio)
  channel!.invokeMethod("setMinZoomLevel", arguments: minZoom)
  channel!.invokeMethod("setMaxZoomLevel", arguments: maxZoom)
  channel!.invokeMethod("setMinExposure", arguments: minExposure)
  channel!.invokeMethod("setMaxExposure", arguments: maxExposure)
  channel!.invokeMethod("setOnFrontCamera", arguments:   cameraPosition == .front)
 }
}
```

So my question is how to handle the platform thread without using plugin ?

Comment: FYI, the Flutter task queue API is unrelated to your use case, as it only applies to calls from Dart to the host, not host to Dart. Host to Dart must still always use the platform thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed [in the official platform channel documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#jumping-to-the-main-thread-in-ios):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // Make your invokeMethod calls here.
}
```

Comment: I already wrapped my invoke Methods with this but it doesn't change anything since I haven't registered the channels as mentioned above. And so I still get the error

Comment: @nicover I don't know what you mean by "haven't registered the channels", but that error message shouldn't have anything to do with handler registration. If you are getting the error message at the beginning of your post from a call to `invokeMethod` inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async` then please file a Flutter issue with a complete reproducible test case, because that should not be possible.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for infos I'm going to write a sample code to try to reproduce this issue for an iOS camera native very basic because I still don't know why I'm getting this even with ```DispatchQueue.main.async```. If this persist, I will fill an Flutter issue then

Comment: The problem was our code mistake. So ```DispatchQueue.main.async``` should wrap all ```invokeMethod```. Thanks for your help @smorgan